# Samsung Tab OS 6.0.1 does not list external storage?

Tags: android

I have following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

try {
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In my Samsung phone 6.0.1, it lists my SD Card, but in my Samsung tab 6.0.1, it doesn't. For sure both of them has allowed the permission.

What could be wrong? Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before use the ROM custom action to select a file, did you try use the 
Android standard way to select a file?

If the standard way don't work, fallback to the ROM's custom one.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
Intent i = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file to Upload");
if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(i);
}
```